# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python' --> following tensorflow debugger tutorial

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the:
https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger

and my imports look like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.python.debug as tf_debug
```

I have the newest tensorflow:

```
tensorflow==1.8.0
```

but I get the following error:

```
  File "/home/lpp/Desktop/minion-basecaller/mincall/train/_train.py", line 16, in <module>
    import tensorflow.python.debug as tf_debug
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'python'
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you writing tensorflow.python.debug? try this :

```
import tensorflow.debug as tf_debug
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.debug'

I'm following official instructions

Comment: so , something of their Packages Have A Mistake